# Bundle Install for Hart'l RoR Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Hart'l's RoR tutorial, Section 1.2.5 - is this a command that we need to implement? I do not understand what is being asked here? Additionally, I do not know how to implement what he is asking? I am a  beginner and successfully implemented the previous section, but am unsure how to do this part.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What line are you confused about?

Comment: I ran the first subl Gemfile portion. But then is he suggesting that there are changes being made to get more recent versions of the gems? I do not understand what to do here.

Comment: In particular Listing 1.2.5. I got the output shown in Listing 1.2.4; am I supposed to do something to get the output in Listing 1.2.5? And how do I do this? I am using Windows

Comment: Also when I type Bundle Install, nothing seems to happen

Comment: When I type in Bundle Install my command prompt (windows) says bundler::gemfilenotfound

Comment: Go to the App's root folder and run `bundle install`

Comment: I am still getting gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3 instead of 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use rvm to install your environment then you can try this:

Edit your **Gemfile**, replace 3.2.3 to 3.2.5 in sass-rails version. Then try

```
sudo bundle install
```

if it says that gem sass-rails is missing then write:

```
sudo gem install sass-rails -v 3.2.5
```

If you have used rvm then the command should be changed to:

```
rvmsudo gem install sass-rails -v 3.2.5
```

And it would be better if you could post your gemfile.